# Problems with mysql and mysqli

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, mysqli

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\swift\core\functions\general.php on line 49
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: conn in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\swift\core\functions\users.php on line 85
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\swift\core\functions\users.php on line 85
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysqli_result() in C:\xampp\htdocs\swift\core\functions\users.php:86
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\swift\loginact.php(14): f_exists('')
>   #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\swift\core\functions\users.php on line 86

I keep on getting those errors but i cant find a way, i already tried everything.. Hopefully someone can help me as I am new to php.
Ive been doing this for almost like a day now and i cannot figure out the answer.

**This is the General.php.**

```
<?php

     $connect_error = 'Sorry, there was some connectivity issue!';
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
    $db = mysqli_select_db($conn, 'swift');


    function activation($to, $subject, $body) {
        mail($to, $subject, $body, 'From: swift@srikanthnatarajan.com');
    }

    function recovery_user_pass($to, $subject, $body) {
        mail($to, $subject, $body, 'From: swift@srikanthnatarajan.com');
    }

    function f_protect_page() {
        if(f_logged_in() === false) {
            header('Location: flogin.php');
            exit();     
        } 
    }

    function user_protect_page() {
        if(f_logged_in() === false) {
            header('Location: fprotect.php');
            exit();     
        } 
    }

    function use_protect_page() {
        if(f_logged_in() === true) {
            header('Location: fprotect.php');
            exit();     
        } 
    }

    function f_logged_in_redirect() {
        if(f_logged_in() === true) {
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        }
    }

    function array_sanitize($item) {
        $item = htmlentities(strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($item)));
    }

    function sanitize($data) {
        return htmlentities(strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($data)));
    }

    function output_errors($errors) {
        return '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $errors) . '</li></ul>';
    }

?>
```

**this is the USERS.PHP can someone please check this.**

```
<?php

$connect_error = 'Sorry, there was some connectivity issue!';
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
    $db = mysqli_select_db($conn, 'swift');



    function f_recover($mode, $f_mailid) {
        $mode = sanitize($mode);
        $f_mailid = sanitize($f_mailid);
        $f_data = f_data(f_id_from_email($f_mailid),'f_id','f_fname','f_uname');
        if ($mode == 'f_uname') {
            recovery_user_pass($f_mailid, 'Recovery: Your username', "Hello " . $f_data['f_fname'] . ",\n\nYour username is: " . $f_data['f_uname'] . "\n\n-Swift Airlines");
        }
        else if($mode == 'f_password') {
            $generated_password = substr(md5(rand(999, 999999)), 0, 8);
            f_change_password($f_data['f_id'], $generated_password);

            update_f($f_data['f_id'], array('f_passrec' => '1'));

            recovery_user_pass($f_mailid, 'Recovery: Your password', "Hello " . $f_data['f_fname'] . ",\n\nYour new password is: " . $generated_password . "\n\n-TOFSIS");
        }
    }

    function f_activate($f_mailid, $f_mailcode) {
        $f_mailid = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['f_mailid']);
        $f_mailcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['f_mailcode']);
        if(mysqli_result(mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(`f_id`) FROM `flight_users` WHERE `f_mailid` = '$f_mailid' AND `f_mailcode` = '$f_mailcode' AND `f_active` = 0"), 0) == 1) {
            mysqli_query("UPDATE `flight_users` SET `f_active` = 1 WHERE `f_mailid` = '$f_mailid' ");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function update_f($f_id, $update_data) {
        $update = array();
        array_walk($update_data, 'array_sanitize');
        foreach ($update_data as $field => $data) {
            $update[] = '`' . $field . '` = \'' . $data . '\'';
        }       
        mysqli_query("UPDATE `flight_users` SET " . implode(', ',$update) . "WHERE `f_id` = $f_id") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    }

    function f_change_password($f_id, $f_password) {
        $f_id = (int)$f_id;
        $f_password = md5($f_password);
        mysqli_query("UPDATE `flight_users` SET `f_password` = '$f_password', `f_passrec` = 0 WHERE `f_id` = $f_id");
    }

    function register_f($register_data) {
        array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
        $register_data['f_fname'] = ucwords(strtolower($register_data['f_fname']));
        $register_data['f_lname'] = ucwords(strtolower($register_data['f_lname']));
        $register_data['f_password'] = md5($register_data['f_password']);
        $register_data['f_uname'] = strtolower($register_data['f_uname']);
        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
        $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

        mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `flight_users` ($fields, `f_regdate`) VALUES ($data, NOW())");
        activation($register_data['f_mailid'], 'Swift Airlines: Activate your account', "Hello " . $register_data['f_fname'] . ", \n\nYou need to activate your account in order to use the features of Swift Airlines. Please click the link below: \n\nhttp://srikanthnatarajan.com/swift/activate.php?f_mailid=" . $register_data['f_mailid'] . "&f_mailcode=" . $register_data['f_mailcode'] . " \n\n-Swift Airlines");
    }

    function f_data($f_id){
        $data = array();
        $f_id = (int)$f_id;
        $func_num_args = func_num_args();
        $func_get_args = func_get_args();
        if($func_num_args > 1) {
            unset($func_get_args[0]);
            $fields = '`'. implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`'; 
            $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query("SELECT $fields FROM `flight_users` WHERE `f_id` = $f_id"));            
            return $data;
        }
    }

    function f_logged_in() {
        return (isset($_SESSION['f_id'])) ? true : false;
    }

    function f_exists($f_uname) {
        $f_uname = sanitize($f_uname);
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(`f_id`) FROM `flight_users` WHERE `f_uname`= '$f_uname'");
        return (mysqli_result($conn, $query, 0) == 1) ? true : false; 
    }

    function f_email_exists($f_mailid) {
        $f_mailid = sanitize($f_mailid);
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(`f_id`) FROM `flight_users` WHERE `f_mailid`= '$f_mailid'");
        return (mysqli_result($conn, $query, 0) == 1) ? true : false; 
    }

    function f_regid_exists($f_regid) {
        $f_regid = sanitize($f_regid);
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(`f_id`) FROM `flight_users` WHERE `f_regid`= '$f_regid'");
        return (mysqli_result($conn, $query, 0) == 1) ? true : false; 
    }

    function f_active($f_uname) {
        $f_uname = sanitize($f_uname);
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(`f_id`) FROM `flight_users` WHERE `f_uname`= '$f_uname' AND `f_active` = 1");
        return (mysqli_result($conn, $query, 0) == 1) ? true : false; 
    }

    function f_id_from_username($f_uname) {
        $f_uname = sanitize($f_uname);
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `f_id` FROM `flight_users` WHERE `f_uname` = '$f_uname'");
        return mysqli_result($conn, $query, 0, 'f_id');
    } 

    function f_id_from_email($f_mailid) {
        $f_mailid = sanitize($f_mailid);
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `f_id` FROM `flight_users` WHERE `f_mailid` = '$f_mailid'");
        return mysqli_result($conn, $query, 0, 'f_id');
    } 

    function f_login($f_uname, $f_password) {
        $f_id = f_id_from_username($f_uname);
        $f_uname = sanitize($f_uname);
        $f_password = md5($f_password);
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(`f_id`) FROM `flight_users` WHERE `f_uname`= '$f_uname' AND `f_password` = '$f_password'");
        return (mysqli_result($conn, $query, 0) == 1) ? $f_id : false;
    }

?>
```

**and this is the Loginact.php------------------**

```
<?php

        $title = 'Swift Airlines | Login Error';
    include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/swift/core/init.php';


    if(empty($_POST) === false) {
        $f_uname = $_POST['f_uname'];
        $f_password = $_POST['f_password'];

        if(empty($f_uname) === true || empty($f_password) === true){
            $errors[] = 'You need to enter both, the username and the password!';
        } 
        else  if (f_exists($f_uname)===false) {
            $errors[] = 'No such user exists! Please register!';
        }
        else if(f_active($f_uname)===false) {
            $errors[] = 'Please activate your account!';
        }
        else {

            if(strlen($f_password)>32) {
                $errors[] = 'Password too long!';
            }

            $f_login = f_login($f_uname, $f_password);
            if($f_login===false) {
                $errors[] = 'Username and Password do not match!';
            }
            else {
                $_SESSION['f_id'] = $f_login;
                header('Location: http://localhost/swift/index.php');
                exit();
            }
        }       
    }
    else {
            $errors[] = 'No Log In credentials received!';
        }

    include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/swift/includes/overall/header.php';

    if(empty($errors) === false) {
?>
    <br/><h4>We tried to log you in, but : </h4><br/>

<?php
    echo output_errors($errors);
    }

    include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/swift/includes/overall/footer.php';

?>
```

I keep on getting those errors but i cant find a way, i already tried everything.. Hopefully someone can help me as I am new to php.
Ive been doing this for almost like a day now and i cannot figure out the answer.

i know php is kind of hard yea and ive been looking for the answer for almost a day now. Im just new to programming and im doing my best to study hard about these kind of things hopefully someone can help me.

And i hope i can learn more about php and other programming language here.. ill keep looking for the answer even if im asking right now.. big thanks though.

Comment: where is `html` or `css` ?

Comment: FYI when you post line numbers (from errors), identify these lines in the code.

Comment: You can use classes and objects for it

Comment: Your sanitize function is filtering and escaping.  It's trying to be a one size fits all magic sanitizer.  Learn to escape appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you tried everything!

It looks as if you are trying to migrate from mysql_ functions to mysqli_.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) for mysqli_fetch_array:

> ```
> $query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID LIMIT 3";
> $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
>
> /* numeric array */
> $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
> printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
> ```

$link is your mysqli connection.  In your code it is $conn.

Within your functions you have a scope issue.  $conn is in the global scope, so is not set within the function's scope.

Break it down, start with something like your f_id_from_email function, and follow and try to translate the manual's examples.

The error messages are actually quite helpful if read.  But you are likely overwhelmed, as you are faced with many.

> Call to undefined function mysqli_result()

That's because there is no mysqli_result function.

Answer (score 0):

1- general.php line 49: look at [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), in procedural code, you must specify 2 arguments, the link (or connection) and the string.

```
function array_sanitize($conn,$item) {
        $item = htmlentities(strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$item)));
    }

function sanitize($conn,$data) {
    return htmlentities(strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$data)));
}
```

2- users.php, both on line 85, the $conn does not exist in the scope of the function. Pass $conn as an argument to the function and call it with ($conn,$f_uname).

```
function f_exists($conn,$f_uname) {
    $f_uname = sanitize($f_uname);
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(`f_id`) FROM `flight_users` WHERE `f_uname`= '$f_uname'");
    return (mysqli_result($conn, $query, 0) == 1) ? true : false; 
}
```

3- your question at line 86, it is the same as my #2 point.